# Merge two dataframes on the basis of one common column! Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes
name of 1st dataframe is (order), it has 444 rows and a few columns including a column called 'barcode'
name of 2nd dataframe is (bookerdf), it also has 444 rows and a few columns including a column called 'barcode'

'barcode' columns in two different dataframes are same. having same values, even the order is same.
I am trying to merge these dataframes in a way that, the resultant dataframe should have same number of rows(444) with the first column should be of 'barcode' followed by columns of 1st dataframe and then 2nd dataframe respectively.

Here are a few commands i have tried myself to do it

```
order_booker = pd.merge(left = order, right = booker, how='left', left_on = 'barcode', right_on='barcode')
```

It gives the resultant dataframe (order_booker) having 1045 rows and few columns. I dont know why,
can somebody help me find a suitable solution?

Comment: if barcode is duplicated in any of your dataframes you will get a many to many result.

Comment: so should i remove barcode column from any of those dataframes?

Comment: don’t think so as it is the linking variable. You need to update your question and specify what is the expected output